# How do I allow a variable that increments throughout the body of a JavaScript file to retain its new values after page reload

Tags: javascript, variables, reload

Basically, I'm trying to add "points" values on a web game I made and when I reload the page using the reload() function, i lose the incremented value and the points variable initializes back to 0 (which i understand). Im trying to overcome this issue but cant figure it out. 
I tried looking up this solution numerous times but nothing works. There was a solution online which stated to SessionStorage Object to get and set the value but that didn't work.

```
    //totalPoints += pointsEarned;
    //sessionStorage.setItem("totalPoints", totalPoints);
    //finalTotalPoints = sessionStorage.getItem("totalPoints");
    //document.getElementById("pointsValue").innerHTML = numOfHints;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `localStorage`.
For example:

1.Set value: `localStorage.setItem("counter", 0);`
 2.Get value: `JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("counter"))`